# How can I add a decorator to an existing object method?

Tags: python, decorator

If I'm using a module/class I have no control over, how would I decorate one of the methods?

I understand I can: `my_decorate_method(target_method)()` but I'm looking to have this happen wherever `target_method` is called without having to do a search/replace.

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it's possible, but there are several problems.
First whet you get method from class in obvious way you get a warper object but not the function itself.

```
class X(object):
    def m(self,x):
        print x

print X.m           #>>> <unbound method X.m>
print vars(X)['m']  #>>> <function m at 0x9e17e64>

def increase_decorator(function):
    return lambda self,x: function(self,x+1)
```

Second I don't know if settings new method will always work:

```
x = X()
x.m(1)         #>>> 1
X.m = increase_decorator( vars(X)['m'] )
x.m(1)         #>>> 2
```

Answer (score 8):

Don't do this.

Use inheritance.

```
import some_module

class MyVersionOfAClass( some_module.AClass ):
    def someMethod( self, *args, **kwargs ):
        # do your "decoration" here.
        super( MyVersionOfAClass, self ). someMethod( *args, **kwargs )
        # you can also do "decoration" here.
```

Now, fix you main program to use `MyVersionOfAClass` instead of `some_module.AClass`.

Comment: That was the original way I looked at the problem but it was a lot of work. The method in the accepted answer is useful to know - even if it isn't the most correct way to do things.

Comment: It's not a matter of "more correct" as much as a matter of "readable" and "maintainable".  Your use case is the *exact* reason that OO languages have inheritance.  It may appear as a lot of work, but it is what every other programmer expects to see.  In the long run, funny dynamic decorators are a liability.  Plain old inheritance will not become a liability.