# python - how to apply decorators to Python functions written in C?

Tags: python, c, cpython, micropython

*Prefer a micropython answer but will accept CPython*

I'm implementing a Python function in C.

How do you apply a decorator to Python function written in C?

Comment: You should check out the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420484/how-can-i-add-a-decorator-to-an-existing-object-method).

Comment: Wouldn't the function be exposed through the Python API? And then you can just apply the decorator at that level?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Decorators can be invoked with a function as their argument.  So if you would have written this (in Python):

```
@mydeco
def myfunc(x, y):
    return x * y
```

You can instead write this:

```
def myimpl(x, y):
    return x * y

myfunc = mydeco(myimpl)
```

You can then move `myimpl` to C.

If your decorator takes arguments:

```
myfunc = mydeco(a, b)(myimpl)
```

Comment: Suggest also demonstrating passing arguments to the decorator: `@mydeco(1,2,3) def myfunc(...)` -> `myfunc = mydeco(1,2,3)(myimpl)`.  Double function call parentheses are surprising the first several times you see them, and it's not obvious from the documentation that this is how you do it.